# Equivalent to cat <<EOF in golang

Tags: shell, go, kubectl

I am trying to perform the equiavalent of this:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testMap
  namespace: default
data:
  details:
    host: "localhost:${reg_port}"
EOF
```

in golang.

My current attempt boils down to:

```
func generateConfig(port string) string {
    return `
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: testMap
  namespace: default
data:
  details:
    host: "localhost:" + port`
}

func main() {
  exec.Command("kubectl", "apply", "-f", "-", generateConfig(5000))
}
```

I was not particularly surprised to find it did not work, with error:

```
error: Unexpected args: [
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: testMap
    namespace: default
data:
    details:
        host: "localhost:5000"]
```

I recognise that I am passing these as args and that kubectl expects a file, however I find myself at a complete loss at how I might continue.

I would rather not make a temporary file or call a separate bash script since this seems messier than I would hope is necessary.

Comment: the `cat` in your shell command is pointless.  `kubectl apply -f - <<EOF` works just as well.

Comment: BTW, re: "rather not make a temporary file" -- your shell program __does__ create a temporary file; it's just doing it under the hood (and deleting it for you automatically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) is directed to the command's stdin.

Here's how to set the [command's stdin](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Stdin) to the result of generateConfig:

```
cmd := exec.Command("kubectl", "apply", "-f", "-")
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(generateConfig("5000"))

if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: They're not quite identical under-the-hood, since heredocs and herestrings are implemented by writing temporary files and connecting them to stdin, rather than via pipelines or FIFOs, but I'd be astonished if kubectl knew the difference.

Comment: ...if someone with a different use case required _completely_ identical behavior, though, I'd set `cmd.Stdin` to point to a file created with `ioutil.TempFile` or such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The behavior is identical because the here document in OP's question is for the `cat` command, not `kubectl`.

Comment: Good point; quite right.